# Insert JSON format in Mysql query using C++

Tags: c++, mysql, json, raspberry-pi2

I am using JSON format to save data in my c++ program , i want to send it to MySql database (the table tab has one column with type : TEXT) but the query failed (tested also VARCHAR and CHAR )

this is a part of the code since we are not interrested in the rest

```
     string json_example = "{\"array\":[\"item1\",\"item2\"], \"not an array\": \"asdf\"}";
   mysql_init(&mysql);  //initialize database connection
   string player="INSERT INTO tab values (\"";
    player+= json_example; 
    player += "\")"; 
    connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,HOST,USER,PASSWD,DB,0,NULL,0); 
// save data to database
   query_state=mysql_query(connection, player.c_str());  // use player.c_str()
```

to show the final query that will be used : cout << player gives  :

> INSERT INTO tab values ("{"array":["item1","item2"], "not an
>   array": "asdf"}")

using for example string json_example = "some text"; is working 
but with the json format it is not working , maybe the problem came from the use of curly bracket {} or double quotes "" but i haven't find a way to solve it .

i'm using :
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (armv7l)  under raspberry pi 2

Any help will be appreciated , thanks .

Comment: You may need to escape your quotes like: `json_example = "{\\\"array...` because the SQL uses quotes. You'd need a triple escape `\\\\`, 2 for the backslash `\\` and one for the quote.

Comment: @Galik you solution worked fine for me , thanks .... however i think that the method i use is not the correct way to use JSON with MySql do you ?

Comment: @user3530803: What's correct and what not depends on your requirements. Personally, I think it's a horrible idea to store JSON in a database, but then again, I am biased against JSON in general. I have never encountered a situation in which storing unstructured data was preferred over storing structured one, and SQL is an extremely powerful language to define structured data.

Comment: @ChristianHackl yes i agree , so JSON could be used to store data and retreive them from a file for example not with databases

Comment: @user3530803: The ability to use text files for storage is one of the reasons you might have chosen JSON in the first place. Storing the JSON in a database defeats this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). See [prepared statements documentation in the MySQL reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-prepared-statement-functions.html).

Prepared statements are more correct, safer, possibly faster, and keep your code cleaner. You get all those benefits and don't need to escape anything. There is hardly a reason not to use them.

---

Something like this might work. But take it with a grain of salt, because I have **not tested or compiled** it. It should just give you the general idea:

```
MYSQL_STMT* const statement = mysql_stmt_init(&mysql);
std::string const query = "INSERT INTO tab values(?)";
mysql_stmt_prepare(statement, query, query.size());
MYSQL_BIND bind[1] = {};
bind[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
bind[0].buffer = json_example.c_str();
bind[0].buffer_length = json_example.size();
mysql_stmt_bind_param(statement, bind);
mysql_stmt_execute(statement);
```

Comment: this magic wich i have never heard about is working :) thanks for adding the code , i have just copy & paste it and compiled by `g++ -I/usr/include/mysql -std=c++0x -o outf jsonToMySql.cpp \`mysql_config --cflags --libs\` `

Comment: @user3530803: Once you get used to prepared statements, you will never again want to use string concatenation to build queries :) Note that prepared statements are also your first line of defense against SQL injections.

Comment: please why you have added "?" in the query .... i heard also about MySql connector ... wich one is better ?

Comment: @user3530803: The `?` means *"insert the parameter here"*. I am not familiar with MySQL connector, sorry. Even if I was familiar with it, "better" is always relative. In any case, knowledge of prepared statements is a must for a professional database programmer.

Comment: @user3530803: I'd like to add that this is fundamentally different to using `+` to concatenate strings. Your original code sent a complete, fixed query to the database. With prepared statements, you supply more logic and let the database itself insert the parameter **after** the query has been parsed. So whatever is in your parameter does not affect parsing.